# How to build a web app CRUD application that works with Moodle?

Tags: web-applications, moodle

Is there any external web application or any tool that take users information and store it in Moodle database or Moodle cloud. So i can create, read, update, and delete data in Moodle database?. Any leads are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use moodle web services for that https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services

Comment: Thank you for the response, i will go through it.